How achieve category name over the bar chart in Power BI?
I am trying to make clustered or stacked bar chart with Rooms category in Y-Axis and Counts in X-Axis. What I achieved looks like the below image.

To manage the left space, can I have the category names over the respective bars that would look like the below Image?

